# Is there similar function in c++ like subprocess.Popen() in python?

Tags: python, c++, shell, exec

I am wondering if there is **similar** function in c++ like subprocess.Popen() in python that would give me results given the execution list as the function's parameter.

Answer (score 2):

- If you have POSIX available, `popen()` is a possibility: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html
- More C++-ish is Boost::process, https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/process.html

Both of those will take a small amount of wrangling to get from whatever list-of-arguments you have to something they can use (`popen()` expects a command to pass to the shell, like `Popen()` when *args* is a string).

Comment: Thanks. popen() is the command I was looking for.

Comment: Additionally this link have helped me: https://www.jeremymorgan.com/tutorials/c-programming/how-to-capture-the-output-of-a-linux-command-in-c/